# How can i fix beacons position in android and find the user location using beacon position?

Tags: android, location, beacon

I need to set my beacons position like below: Beacon 1: (0,0) Beacon
2: (0,10)

According to that beacons position need to find user's phone location.

All these action i want to perform into android application.

If anyone have any idea then please share with me.

Answer (score 0):

For determining locations You can use [Trilateration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trilateration), but You need at least 3 beacons (for example take a look at [this](http://bits.citrusbyte.com/indoor-positioning-with-beacons/)).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I already seen given link but i don't get exact solutions from it.

Can you please provide me demo app with source code for same?

My Requirement: 

I have to fix beacon position in my office. Once its fix than after I have to find that users are where in my office using nearest beacon and send that location to my server.